# can not solve datatable error http://datatables.net/tn/4

Tags: asp.net-core, datatables

I'm implementing asp.net core 3.1. I have a JQuery Datatable that its first column has checkboxes. and I want after user checks some of rows then a message shows the selected rows' information to the user and according to what user previously selected a button, it should change the status of those selected data and update the status of those data in DataTable. Now for updating those data, I get the following error:
DataTables warning: table id=myDummyTable - Requested unknown parameter 'productRequestNo' for row 4, column 2. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Here is what I have tried till now:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Style;
using System.IO;
using static Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbLoggerCategory;
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace project.Controllers
{


    public class productrequestersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly CSDDashboardContext _context;
        private MyCookie mycookie;
      

        private readonly LDap.IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;

        public productrequestersController(LDap.IAuthenticationService authenticationService, CSDDashboardContext context, IHttpContextAccessor ihttp)
        {
           
            _context = context;

            _authenticationService = authenticationService;

            mycookie = new MyCookie(ihttp);
        }

  
      

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetproductrequestersData()
        {

            try
            {
                var draw = HttpContext.Request.Form["draw"].FirstOrDefault();
                // Skiping number of Rows count  
                var start = Request.Form["start"].FirstOrDefault();
                // Paging Length 10,20  
                var length = Request.Form["length"].FirstOrDefault();
                // Sort Column Name  
                var sortColumn = Request.Form["columns[" + Request.Form["order[1][column]"].FirstOrDefault() + "][name]"].FirstOrDefault();
                // Sort Column Direction ( asc ,desc)  
                var sortColumnDirection = Request.Form["order[1][dir]"].FirstOrDefault();
                // Search Value from (Search box)  
                var searchValue = Request.Form["search[value]"].FirstOrDefault();

                //Paging Size (10,20,50,100)  
                int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
                int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
                int recordsTotal = 0;


                var vwReportData = from t in _context.VwReport
                                   where t.IsDeleted == false
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       id1 = t.Id,
                                       id = t.Id,
                                       productRequestNo = t.productRequestNo,
                                       requesterName = t.requesterName,
                                       productName = t.productName,
                                       productRequestDate = t.productRequestDate,
                                       logDate = t.LogDate,
                                       itemName = t.itemName,
                                       lastReqStatus = t.LastReqStatus
                                   };



                if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumn) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortColumnDirection)))
                {
                    vwReportData = vwReportData.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + sortColumnDirection);
                }
                //Search  
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue))
                {
                    searchValue = searchValue.Trim();
                    vwReportData = vwReportData.Where(m => m.productRequestNo.ToString() == searchValue || m.productName.Trim().Contains(searchValue) || m.logDate.Contains(searchValue) || m.productRequestDate.Trim().Contains(searchValue) ||
                    m.requesterName.Trim().Contains(searchValue) || m.itemName.Trim().Contains(searchValue));
                }

                //total number of rows count   
                recordsTotal = vwReportData.Count();
                //Paging   
                var data = vwReportData.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
                //Returning Json Data  
                return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data });

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }

        }

  

        public List<string> obtainingData(List<int> Id)
        {

         
            List<string> data = new List<string>();

            ShortproductrequesterJsonTO productrequesterJson = new ShortproductrequesterJsonTO();
         
            //Insert
            for (int i = 0; i < Id.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                var query = (from t in _context.VwReport
                             where t.Id == Id[i]
                             select new
                             {
                                 id = t.Id,
                                 productRequestNo = t.productRequestNo,
                                 requesterName = t.requesterName,
                                 productName = t.productName,
                                 productRequestDate = t.productRequestDate,
                                 logDate = t.LogDate,
                                 itemName = t.itemName,
                                 lastReqStatus = t.LastReqStatus

                             }).ToList();




                foreach (var index in query)
                {
      

                    productrequesterJson = new ShortproductrequesterJsonTO
                    {
                        id1 = index.id,
                        id = index.id,
                        productRequestNo = index.productRequestNo.GetValueOrDefault(),
                        requesterName = index.requesterName,
                        productName = index.productName,
                        productRequestDate = index.productRequestDate,
                        logDate = index.logDate,
                        itemName = index.itemName,
                        lastReqStatus = index.lastReqStatus

                    };
                    string jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(productrequesterJson);
                    data.Add(jsonResult);
                  
                }
            }

            return data;
        }





        public IList<string> selectedListOperation(List<int> Id, string description, string unconfirmedselectedId)
        {
           
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            data = obtainingData(Id);



            Console.WriteLine("unconfirmedselectedId:" + unconfirmedselectedId);
            int lastNumber = Id.LastOrDefault();


            switch (lastNumber)
            {
                case 1:
                    //technical review
                    runningOperationOnSelectedData(Id, description, unconfirmedselectedId, 46);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //confirmation
                    runningOperationOnSelectedData(Id, description, unconfirmedselectedId, 47);
                    break;
            }

            return data;
        }

        public bool runningOperationOnSelectedData(List<int> Id, string description, string unconfirmedReason, int status)
        {
            var lastchangesDate = PersianDateTime.Now.Date.ToString(format: "yyyy/MM/dd").PersianToEnglish();
            //int lastNumber = Id.LastOrDefault();

            int productrequesterHistoryRecordId;



            for (int t = 0; t < Id.Count - 1; t++)
            {

                var productrequester = _context.productrequesterHistory
               .Include(a => a.productrequester).Where(a => a.Id == a.productrequester.LastRequestStatus)
               .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.productrequesterId == Id[t]);

                productrequester.Result.LastReqStatus = status;


                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(unconfirmedReason))
                {
                    
                    int unconfirmedReasonNumber = Int32.Parse(unconfirmedReason);
                    productrequesterHistoryRecordId = AccessproductrequesterHistoryDouble(productrequester.Result.productrequester.Id, lastchangesDate, productrequester.Result.SentResponseType ?? 0, unconfirmedReasonNumber, status, description).Result;
                }
                else
                {
                    productrequesterHistoryRecordId = AccessproductrequesterHistoryDouble(productrequester.Result.productrequester.Id, lastchangesDate, productrequester.Result.SentResponseType ?? 0, productrequester.Result.UnconfirmedReason ?? 0, status, description).Result;
                }
                // Save changes in database

                productrequester.Result.productrequester.LastRequestStatus = productrequesterHistoryRecordId;
                _context.SaveChanges();

            }
            return true;
        }

        public async Task<int> AccessproductrequesterHistoryDouble(int myproductrequesterId, string lastChangesDate, int sentResponseType, int unconfirmedReason, int lastReqStatus, String desc)
        {
            var task = productrequesterHistoryLog(myproductrequesterId, lastChangesDate, sentResponseType, unconfirmedReason, lastReqStatus, desc);
            Debug.WriteLine("task:" + task);
            int result = await task;

            return await Task.FromResult(result);

        }

    }

}
```

//Here is the index.cshtml:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="~/js/DataTable/DataTableCheckbox/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="~/js/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="~/js/DataTable/DataTableCheckbox/dataTables.checkboxes.min.js"></script>


<script>
    keepSelectedRows = [];
    var operationNumber = '';
    var oTable;
    var selectedIds = [];
    var descriptionText = "";

    var theRowObject='';
    var rowSelectedId='';


    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


           oTable= $('#myDummyTable').DataTable({

                'orderClasses': false,

                "processing": true, // for show progress bar
                "serverSide": true, // for process server side
                "filter": true, // this is for disable filter (search box)
                "orderMulti": false,


               'columnDefs': [
                   {
                       'targets': 0,
                       "searching": false,
                       'checkboxes': {
                           'selectRow': true
                         }
                    },
                        {
                            'targets': 1,
                            "searching": false,
                            "visible": false
                        }
               ],
                rowId: "id",

                'select': {
                    'style': 'multi',
                    'selector': 'td:first-child'
                },
                'order': [[1, 'asc']],

                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                //--------------------------------------------------------
                
            "ajax": {
                "url": "productrequesters/GetproductrequestersData",
                "type": "POST",
                "datatype": "json",
            },


                { "data": "id1" },
                { "data": "id", "name": "id", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "productRequestNo", "name": "productRequestNo", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "requesterName", "name": "requesterName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "productName", "name": "productName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "productRequestDate", "name": "productRequestDate", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "logDate", "name": "logDate", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "itemName", "name": "itemName", "autoWidth": true },
                { "data": "lastReqStatus", "name": "lastReqStatus", "autoWidth": true },
                {
                defaultContent: '<input type="button" class="Edit" value="edit"/>'
                },
            ]
    });

        //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


             oTable.on('click', '.Edit', function () {


                 var row = $(this).closest('tr');
               
                 var newRow = oTable.row(row);

                 theRowObject = newRow;


                  $('#keepRow').val(newRow);


                 rowSelectedId = oTable.row(row).data().id;



               var tempurl = '@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","productrequesters")'+'/'+ rowSelectedId;

               var link = document.createElement("a");
               link.href = tempurl


              var url = link.protocol + "//" + link.host + link.pathname + link.search + link.hash;
    

              showInPopup(url,'edit');

    });
});


    function sitejsObject(myModifiedDataObject) {
        console.log('theRowObject.id:' + rowSelectedId);

        console.log('myModifiedDataObject.id:'+myModifiedDataObject.id);
        if (rowSelectedId == myModifiedDataObject.id) {
            oTable.row(theRowObject).data(myModifiedDataObject).draw(false);
        }
        else {
            oTable.row.add(myModifiedDataObject).draw();
        }

    };



    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


            $('#grantAccess,#accessDenial,#confirmation,#unconfirmation,#technicalReview').click(function () {

                $("#descId").val('');
                //$('#displaySelectList').val("0");
                $("#modalbody").empty();

                if (this.id == 'unconfirmation') {
                    $('#unconfirmedReason').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
                    $('#displaySelectList').show();
                }
                else {
                    $('#displaySelectList').hide();
                }

                var OTable = $("#myDummyTable").dataTable();

                $("input[type=checkbox]:checked", OTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function () {


                    var row = $(this).closest('tr');


                   var newRow = oTable.row(row);

                    console.log("newRow:"+newRow);
 
                    keepSelectedRows.push(newRow);
    
                    selectedIds.push($(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text());

                    var Id = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text();
                    var productRequestNO = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(2)").text();
                    var requesterName = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(3)").text();
                    var productName = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(4)").text();
                    var productRequestDate = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(5)").text();
                    var LogDate = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(6)").text();
                    var itemName = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(7)").text();
                    var LastReqStatus = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(8)").text();

                    var markup = "<tr><td>"+ Id + "</td><td>" + productRequestNO + "</td><td>" + requesterName + "</td><td>" + productName + "</td><td>" + productRequestDate + "</td><td>"  + LogDate + "</td><td>" + itemName + "</td><td>" + LastReqStatus + "</td></tr>";

                    $("#classTable").append(markup);

                });

                if (this.id == 'technicalReview') {
               
                    selectedIds.push('001');
                }
                else if (this.id == 'confirmation') {
                    selectedIds.push('002');
                }
               



                $("input[name='hiddeninput']").val(selectedIds);

                if (selectedIds.length <= 1) {
                    alert("non record");
                }
                else {
                    $('#showDataModal').modal('show');

                }

            });

        $("#deletethem").click(function () {
            if ($("input[type=checkbox]").is(':checked')) {
                var oTable = $("#myDummyTable").dataTable();
                $("input[type=checkbox]:checked", oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function () {
                    $(this).prop("checked", false);
                });
            }
        });


            });

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
          $("#exitbutton").click(function () {
              selectedIds = [];

            $('#showDataModal').modal('toggle');
          });
     });

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var unconfirmedselectedId;
        $("#unconfirmedReason").change(function () {

             unconfirmedselectedId = $('#unconfirmedReason').val();

            });


        $("#deletethem").click(function () {
            var OTable = $("#myDummyTable").DataTable();
            var descContent=$.trim($("#descId").val());
    $.ajax({
        url: "productrequesters/selectedListOperation",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        cache: false,                  /*descriptionText*/
        data: { "Id": selectedIds, "description": descContent, "unconfirmedselectedId": unconfirmedselectedId },
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
//here I update the selected rows in datatable
                OTable.row(keepSelectedRows.pop()).data(data).draw(false);

            });

        }
    });
  });
});

</script>

@*************************************@
<div class="my-5 col-sm-12 p-4">

    <table id="myDummyTable" class="table m-table mytable table-striped table-bordered mb-4" style="width: auto;">
        <thead>
            <tr id="headerrow">
                <th>
                    <input type='checkbox'>
                </th>
                <th hidden>
                    ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    request number
                </th>
                <th>
                    requester
                </th>
                <th>
                    product
                </th>
                <th>
                    request date
                </th>
                <th>
                    last change date
                </th>
                <th>
                    item
                </th>
                <th>
                    last status
                </th>
                <th>
                    operation
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center" style="padding: 23px;">
        <input class="btn" id="technicalReview" type="button" value="technical review" data-whatever="technicalReview" style="margin: 0 0.5em;" />
        <input class="btn" id="confirmation" type="button" value="Confirmation" data-whatever="confirmation" style="margin-left: 0.5rem;" />
       
    </div>
</div>



@*******************************************************************************************@
<div class="modal fade" id="showDataModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" style="overflow:auto;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>Do you agree to change the status?</h4>
            </div>
            <form method="post">

                <div class="row border-light input-group mt-4 mr-1">
                    <div class="form-group col-12" id="displaySelectList" style="display:none;">
                        @Html.ValidationMessage("unconfirmedReason", "type:", new { @class = "d-inline-block col-3 p-0" })
                        @Html.DropDownList("unconfirmedReason", new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["unconfirmedReason"], "Value", "Text"), "select", new { @class = "form-control d-inline-block col-5", id = "unconfirmedReason", style = "left: 2rem" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body pt-0">
                  
                    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenInput" />
                    <div id="result" class="">

                        <table id="classTable" class="table table-bordered" border="1">
                            <thead>
                                <tr id="headerrow">
                                    <th>
                                        request number
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        Requester
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        product
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        request date
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        last change date
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        product
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        last status
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="modalbody">
                            </tbody>

                        </table>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-10 mt-4">
                    <label class="control-label" for="descId">explantaion</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control input-xlarge" placeholder="explanation" id="descId" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer mt-4">
                 
                    <button type="button" id="deletethem" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">confirm</button>
         
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>




@section scripts{

    <script>


    $('#request_layout').css({ "background-color": "rgb(50, 149, 155)" });
    </script>
}
```

//ShortproductrequesterJsonTO

```
 public class ShortproductrequesterJsonTO
    {
        public int id1 { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string productRequestDate { get; set; }
        public int productRequestNo { get; set; }
        public string productName { get; set; }
        public string requesterName { get; set; }
        public string itemName { get; set; }
        public string logDate { get; set; }
        public string lastReqStatus { get; set; }

    }
```

I appreciate if anyone suggests me how can I solve the error.
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
for editing a row by clicking the edit buttun that each row has I used somethink like the following and it works correctly:
//---------------------------------------------------------------

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrEdit(int id, productrequesterViewModel productrequesterviewmodel)
 {

new ShortproductrequesterJsonTO productrequesterJson = new ShortproductrequesterJsonTO
                    {
                        id1 = index.id,
                        id = index.id,
                        productRequestNo = index.productRequestNo.GetValueOrDefault(),
                        requesterName = index.requesterName,
                        productName = index.productName,
                        productRequestDate = index.productRequestDate,
                        logDate = index.logDate,
                        itemName = index.itemName,
                        lastReqStatus = index.lastReqStatus

                    };

return Json(productrequesterJson);
}
```

the above code just when I send one object to ajax call works correctly.

Comment: What jquery is the one updating data in DataTable?And I find you code miss `"columns": [` in `oTable= $('#myDummyTable').DataTable({`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, my datatable has  "columns": [ on top of dara columns, I forgot to mention it in my code. My datatable loads its data correctly. I updated my code where I use jquery to update the data of selected rows.

Comment: I mean which jquery function you used to update the data in datatable.You have many functions,I don't know which one you will get the error.

Comment: OTable.row(keepSelectedRows.pop()).data(data).draw(false);

Comment: Each row has an edit button, and by clicking it, a modal pops up to the user and after modifying the data fields, and by clicking save button, it edits the data in the that row. I used the mentioned function for it as well which works correctly. but after choosing multiple data to update, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think I have to send the array of data in Json type. when I click the edit button to edit just one row I send the data object in json format to ajax call and it works fine. But I don't know how to send the array of data in json format to ajax call.